# RavenDB Error : Only a single concurrent async request is allowed per async client instance

Tags: ravendb

We keep getting this error. In he stack trace, it lists a method that IS NOT async and no other calls are being made to the database.

Would appreciate any assistance.
Thank you.

Comment: Please post full code and full stack trace